# How to install PDCurses with MinGW on Windows?

Tags: dll, mingw, libraries, pdcurses

I have looked all over the internet for installation instructions but could not find one that actually worked. I have downloaded the MinGW-Get application as stated in many websites, but have no idea how to use it. I did find a website with the following instructions:

> HOW TO INSTALL:
>
> Install an ide on your windows machine, I’ll use the simple Dev-Cpp.
>
> Download this zip containing the files you’ll need.
>
> Create a folder called pdcurses and another one called include, inside
>   of it.
>
> Extract panel.h and curses.h in the include fold.
>
> Extract the .dll file in the pdcurses one.
>
> Now open your ide and set the 32-bit version compiler as the default
>   one.
>
> Create a new project, set it up.
>
> On the lefty Treeview, right click on the project icon -> project
>   options
>
> Go to -> Parameters  tab-> Linker -> insert in its box the path to the
>   .dll file you extracted before
>
> Go to -> Files/folders tab
>
> Here you’ll see three inner tabs named: Libraries/Includes/resources
>   folders; inside each of them you have to insert the path to the
>   include folder you created before.

Source: https://hastalafiesta.altervista.org/setup-pdcurses-windows-devcpp/

However, I could not find the .dll or a library file in the PDCurses folder I extracted from the .zip file I downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/3.4/pdc34dllw.zip/download (as stated in the fifth step). I just got started with C++ and libraries and would appreciate it if anyone could provide me some guidance or any useful links.

[image: Edit: This is inside the folder I extracted from sourceforge.]

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't find the .dll or library file? Both pdcurses.dll and pdcurses.lib are in the zip file you linked.

Comment: @ssbssa Yeah... the thing is I cannot find that pdcurses.lib file in that zip file. I also had to download pdcurses.dll from an external website...

Comment: I'm not sure how you can miss them. pdc34dllw.zip only has 4 files inside: pdcurses.lib, pdcurses.dll, panel.h, curses.h

Comment: @ssbssa That’s strange... In the folder I extracted, there are many files: common, demos, docs, and all the files that are not pdcurses.lib or pdcurses.dll.... I could find panel.h and curses.h though.

Comment: @ssbssa P.S. I attached a picture for reference.

Comment: That's not the contents of the zip file you linked. It's the source code of version 3.8, you linked the binary-zip of version 3.4. It seems there are no longer binary builds available since version 3.5. So you either build the latest version yourself, or use the binary of version 3.4.

Comment: @ssbssa Oh man, what a foolish mistake. Thanks for the heads up. Do you know any other ways I can use aside from building it myself? I want to use it for a C++ project on QtCreator. Is it possible for me to just add it to the QtCreator library somehow? This website (https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/wincon/README.md) says I need to "build it" but I just have no idea how or where I can do it...

Comment: Can't you use the dll of version 3.4? Is there any reason you have to use the latest version?

Comment: @ssbssa Yes, I plan to use the version 3.4 as you previously suggested. So... all I have to do is to extract the containing files somewhere and I can use the PDCurses.h file in my projects right away?

Comment: Yes. (Don't forget to add the include and linker path as your posted HOW TO said)